# Spinner onClick show DatePicker Dialog

Tags: android, datepicker, spinner

I want to focus on a Spinner by using the trackball, Click it and then get a DatePicker dialog. I don't actually want to use the spinner idea i just want it to look like it is a spinner. But some problems arise

1.It's not possible to get focus on a spinner unless there are items in it
2.It's not possible to use the onClick() method with a spinner
3.I can't find a way to open a Dialog with the Spinner view.

Probably i'am putting too much effort in it while i could just use a TextView / Button / editText / imageView that i can click on to create a datePick dialog.

Or maybe there's someone with a simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

try that

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html

Comment: it's not what i was looking for but i did just went with the datepicker because what i wanted took me too much time